# binutils bfd links against system iberty instead of built iberty

Tags: makefile, configure, libtool, binutils

When building binutils, the bfd component is failing to link because it is linking against the system version of libiberty instead of the built version under binutuils/libiberty/lib64/libiberty.a.

I can't see a configure argument to allow me to override this.  What's the best way to instruct configure to construct an LD_LIBRARY_PATH that prefers libraries from other components of its build over system versions?  Obviously, it needs system libraries that are prerequisites, so I can't exclude this path entirely.

This is the error, due to the system version having not been compiled correctly.  The version under `binutils/libiberty/lib64` is compiled with -fPIC, so I need to tell configure to use that.

```
/lib64/libiberty.a(cplus-dem.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

It doesn't seem as trivial to specify `.:/usr/lib64:/lib64` since `.` is `binutils/bfd`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the generated automakefile and LDFLAGS was only specifying the system libraries:

```
LDFLAGS := -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib
```

So I specified this as an argument to configure.  Slightly hacky, but can't see a better way out:

```
LDFLAGS="-L./ -L../ -L../libiberty/pic -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib" ./confgiure --enable-shared
```